# How was my email intercepted?

Tags: email, man-in-the-middle, protonmail

I've recently sent an email to a non-Protonmail user, using a code phrase. Someone on the recipient's home network was able to intercept the email and responded to me in detail as to the content of my original email. I don't know much about network security, but I would love  to know how this person managed it? All I know is that the recipient was using the WiFi at home. Is that a weak link?

*To be noted that Proton Mail is an email service that allows the user to encrypt their inbox with their own strong password and also encrypt the sent email with a new password that needs to be communicated to the receiver in order to decrypt the received email.

Comment: You mentioned the interceptor had access to the recipient home network. Does the interceptor had access to the intended recipient computer? If yes, could the interceptor have guessed the recipient's password? Or, maybe the recipient forgot to lock it's computer.

Comment: I'm confused, how is the non-use of Protonmail relevant to anything?

Answer (score 5):

Email is insecure.  It is completely insecure.  Between you and the recipient it likely passed through dozens of servers and for each one it was passed as pure plain text.  Without specific details and logs it is impossible to say where a copy was lifted but regardless you should always ASSUME that anyone can read anything you put in an email.

If that concerns you then you should be encrypting the contents of your email using a tool like GPG.

Comment: Proton mail is a Service that is fully encrypted by the user.  You have to login in the service and then use the strong password to decrypt.  Jefferson used a password to also encrypt the send email, so technically, the email was encrypted until the receiver enters the agreed password.

Comment: I disagree with your this statement. `Email is insecure. It is completely insecure.` Please provide the facts that caused you to make this statement or please edit your answer.